# Demagnetization of a permanent magnet and lenz's law

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

This video ( http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vs3afgStVy4 ) demonstrates lenz's law, if the current produced by the magnet fall induces an opposing magnetic field , after many tries , can this field demagnetize the magnet? or decrease its magnetization ?